# how to set upload button in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using  [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) as per my requirement.

I want to use div as file upload control like when user drag & drop a file in the div it should show uploaded files and when user click "submit" button , it should go to server, next other stuff.

But here I am facing problem like, with Form only it is working,  when i am uploading a file it is directly going to server with file, i have written like

```
 <form action="~/Employer/GetFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm" style="width: 50px; background: none; border: none;">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
 </form>  // Working Fine , 


 <div class="watermark pull-left margin-top-1 dropzone" id="divDropFile"></div> // Not wroking,
```

it should upload file(s) only like   [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) without destination urls, it should go to  server when click on file upload button only. Moreover, file drop is not working.

Please help me anyone.. if it is not possible without form submit, please give any suggestion for alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not on my development computer so I can't try it out, but there are two things that might help.

1) The div that you want to serve as the dropzone hot spot should not have the class dropzone.  It needs the class dz-message.  Write it like this:

```
<div class="watermark pull-left margin-top-1 dz-message" id="divDropFile" data-dz-message></div>
```

2) If you don't want it to automatically send the file to the server, you need to add autoProcessQueue = false in your Dropzone.options object.  You will then need to manually call myDropzone.processQueue() later to upload the files.

Comment: ok But IE, Safari Drag and Drop functionality is not working, was it there default functionality like both browsers doesn't supports it?

Comment: What version of IE and Safari?  Dropzone only supports IE 10+ and Safari 6+.  http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: How you solved it, ? Can you help me ? I have same issue on upload files on button click.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail. I am also facing same issue.